# Is the case of the linear chain of atoms one-dimensional?

Tags: semiconductors

I am currently studying *Diode Lasers and Photonic Integrated Circuits*, second edition, by Coldren, Corzine, and Mashanovitch. In chapter **1.2 ENERGY LEVELS AND BANDS IN SOLIDS**, the authors say the following:

> On the other hand, in a covalently bonded solid like the semiconductor materials we use to make diode lasers, the uppermost energy levels of individual constituent atoms each broaden into bands of levels as the bonds are formed to make the solid. This phenomenon is illustrated in Fig. 1.4. The reason for the splitting can be realized most easily by first considering a single covalent bond. When two atoms are in close proximity, the outer valence electron of one atom can arrange itself into a low-energy *bonding* (symmetric) charge distribution concentrated between the two nuclei, or into a high-energy *antibonding* (antisymmetric) distribution devoid of charge between the two nuclei. In other words, the isolated energy level of the electron is now split into two levels due to the two ways the electron can arrange itself around the two atoms.$^1$ In a covalent bond, the electrons of the two atoms both occupy the lower energy bonding level (provided they have opposite spin), whereas the higher energy antibonding level remains empty.
> $^1$The energy level splitting is often incorrectly attributed to the Pauli exclusion principle, which forbids electrons from occupying the same energy state (and thus forces the split, as the argument goes). In actuality, the splitting is a fundamental phenomenon associated with solutions to the wave equation involving two coupled systems and applies equally to probability, electromagnetic, or any other kind of waves. It has nothing to do with the Pauli exclusion principle.
> [image]
> If another atom is brought in line with the first two, a new charge distribution becomes possible that is neither completely bonding nor antibonding. Hence, a third energy level is formed between the two extremes. When $N$ atoms are covalently bonded into a linear chain, $N$ energy levels distributed between the lowest-energy bonding state and the highest-energy antibonding state appear, forming a band of energies. In our linear chain of atoms, spin degeneracy allows all $N$ electrons to fall into the lower half of the energy band, leaving the upper half of the band empty. However in a three-dimensional crystal, the number of energy levels is more generally equated with the number of unit cells, not the number of atoms. In typical semiconductor crystals, there are two atoms per primitive unit cell. Thus, the first atom fills the lower half of the energy band (as with the linear chain), whereas the second atom fills the upper half, such that the energy band is entirely full.

My question relates to the following section:

> In our linear chain of atoms, spin degeneracy allows all $N$ electrons to fall into the lower half of the energy band, leaving the upper half of the band empty. However in a three-dimensional crystal, the number of energy levels is more generally equated with the number of unit cells, not the number of atoms.

So this explanation seems to be distinguishing between how the energy bands get filled in the case of a linear chain of atoms vs how the energy bands get filled in the case of a crystal. I understand that the case of the crystal is three-dimensional, but is the case of the linear chain of atoms **one**-dimensional? I'm wondering what the correct/accurate way to conceptualize this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the author is trying to compare 1D and 3D rigorously. A perfectly linear chain of covalently bonded atoms doesn't exist in isolation past 3-4 atoms, to my knowledge. (longer polyynes and cumulenes have very slight bond angle deviations and are unstable).

So the 1D description is merely didactic. It's using a hypothetical linear chain of atoms to keep the explanation simple, so you can focus on picturing how the band gap arises.

In reality, semiconductor lattices consist of repeating unit cells that form a band gap.

It seems to me the passage's intent is to communicate that the real-world case of being 3D would still yield a band gap analogously to their hypothetical example. The approach in the text might be summarized as:

1. Here's a hypothetical example of linear atoms to make it easier to conceptualize how the band gap arises from orbital splitting.
2. However in reality, these aren't actually linear atomic chains in semiconductors but 3D chains of unit cells.
3. Nevertheless, 3D unit cells still lead to an analogous splitting effect, so you can safely extend your conception from the hypothetical example to the real world cases.